# convert a string 2d list back to 2d list in python

Tags: python, list

I just started playing around with python.
I know that we can convert any list to a string using str()
Like:

```
>>> l = [[1,1] , [2,2] , [3,3]]
>>> l
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
>>> type(l)
<type 'list'>
>>> str(l)
'[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]'
>>> list_string = str(l)
>>> list_string
'[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]'
>>> type(list_string)
<type 'str'>
```

Is there a way to convert list_string back to a 2d list ??
Basically, is there a function to convert this back to its original form ?

```
old_list = magic_conversion_func(list_string)

>>>old_list
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

I tried list() but that converts every char in the string to a new list element.

```
>>> list(list_string)
['[', '[', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ']', ',', ' ', '[', '2', ',', ' ', '2', ']', ',', ' ', '[', '3', ',', ' ', '3', ']', ']']
```

that is not what I want

Comment: Use `import ast; ast.literal_eval(list_string)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
>>> list_string = '[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]'
>>> import ast
>>> type(ast.literal_eval(list_string))
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: Um...I post too slow. David Robinson's answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

using `eval`

```
>>> l = [[1,1] , [2,2] , [3,3]]
>>> list_string = str(l)
>>> eval(list_string)
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

but `eval` should be used with caution, right? [a thread on `eval` safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do).

This works as well, close to what you tried with `list`:

```
import numpy as np
print np.array(list_string)
```