# Parse string run time parameter to 2D list

Tags: python, command-line, sys

I'm need to pass a 2D list to my program via the command line like the following:

```
python myscript.py [[int,int,int],[int,int,int]]
```

I'm getting the run time param via sys.argv[1], but its interpreted as a string.  I'm having a hard time converting it into a 2D list object.

Comment: voted to close my own question...i found the answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723911/convert-a-string-2d-list-back-to-2d-list-in-python

Answer (score 1):

[ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is what you need to look at.

```
In [7]: x = '[[1002763,201608,1],[1002763,201612,2]]'
In [9]: import ast

In [10]: ast.literal_eval(x)
Out[10]: [[1002763, 201608, 1], [1002763, 201612, 2]]

In [11]: ast.literal_eval(x)[1]
Out[11]: [1002763, 201612, 2]

In [12]: ast.literal_eval(x)[1][2]
Out[12]: 2
```

Comment: yup, just figured it out before you posted. Thanks tho!

Comment: kindly accept and upvote.

Comment: upvoted, but because i found the answer before your post in an already posted answer, i won't mark as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this (Assuming that you are giving valid string as a input)

```
x=sys.argv[1] 

list_2D=[i.split(",") for i in x[2:-2].split("],[")]

print list_2D
```

Output:

```
[['1002763', '201608', '1'], ['1002763', '201612', '2']]
```