# How to perform an operation on all values of a 2D list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I've got a list like so:

```
counters = [["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"]]
```

I'd like to perform an operation to each of the inner values - say concatenation, converting to an `int` and incrementing, etc.

How can I do this for *all* of the list items; given that this is a multi-dimensional list?

Comment: The brackets are part of the representation of the list, they are not part of the list itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) ([nested list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions)):

```
>>> counters = [["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"]]
>>> [[str(int(c)+1) for c in cs] for cs in counters]
[['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1']]
```

BTW, why do you use lists of strings?

I'd rather use a list of numbers (No need to convert to `int`, back to `str`).

```
>>> counters = [0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> [c+1 for c in counters]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, using it as a list of numbers worked :) I'm new to Python, so I didn't know you could do it like that

Answer (score 1):

```
  >>> counter=['0']*10
  >>> counter
   ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
  >>> counter=['1']*10
  >>> counter
  ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
  overwrite a counter with 1,s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> counters = [["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"]]
>>> counters = [ [str(eval(i[0])+1)] for element in counters ]
>>> counters
[['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1']]
```

We can use eval function here. About eval()  [What does Python's eval() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do)

Answer (score 0):

If list comprehension scares you, you can use sub-indexing. For example,

```
for i in range(len(counters)):
    counters[i][0] = str(eval(counters[i][0]) + 1)
```

`counters` is a list of lists, therefore you need to access the subindex of 0 (the first item) before you add to it. `counters[0][0]`, for example, is the first item in the first sublist.

Moreover, each of your subitems is a string, not an integer or float. The `eval` function makes the proper conversion so that we can add 1, and the outer `str` function converts the final answer back to a string.