# Cycling through a group of variables with similar names

Tags: python, variables, loops

Is there a way to cycle through a group of variables with similar names using a for loop in python?

An example (from the nltk library):
I have a group of variables called text1, text2, text3, ..., text9, and I want to do certain operations to all of them without having to explicitly type their names each time, so I'm looking for a way to loop through them like this:

```
for x in range(1, 9):
    text + x.someFunction()
```

I know this is not allowed, but is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: You shouldn't be having those variables in the first place. For example, a list called `texts` would be a better solution, then iterating over that is trivial.

Comment: These variables are in a library (the nltk library) so it isn't me who have named them.

Comment: What a funny library!

Comment: Assuming it's `nltk.book`, these variables hold example data meant to be used at an interactive prompt while following a tutorial.

Comment: yeah, it's nltk.book. I guess it's not meant to be used the way I am trying to use them, but I don't like following tutorials without doing my own experiments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use eval:

```
eval("text" + str(1))
```

For example, to load your values in a map:

```
data = dict()
for x in xrange(1, 9):
    key = "text" + str(x)
    data[key] = eval(key)
```

Or if your variables are objects of a class with a method `someFunction`:

```
for x in xrange(1, 9):
    cmd = "text" + str(x) + ".someFunction()"
    eval(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`

```
for x in range(1, 9):
    eval('text%d' % x).someFunction()
```

Refer: [What does Python's eval() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do) ;

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for v in (text1, text2, text3):
    v.someFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list:

```
texts = [text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7, text8, text9]
```

Then you can iterate over it as you would any other list:

```
for text in texts:
```

I'm assuming the `textn` variables aren't expected to change. If you're using the example data from `nltk.book`, I believe that assumption should hold.