# Python: String indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, influxdb

I get this string from stdin.

> {u'trades': [Custom(time=1418854520, sn=47998, timestamp=1418854517,
>   price=322, amount=0.269664, tid=48106793, type=u'ask',
>   start=1418847319, end=1418847320), Custom(time=1418854520, sn=47997,
>   timestamp=1418854517, price=322, amount=0.1, tid=48106794,
>   type=u'ask', start=1418847319, end=1418847320),
>   Custom(time=1418854520, sn=47996, timestamp=1418854517, price=321.596,
>   amount=0.011, tid=48106795, type=u'ask', start=1418847319,
>   end=1418847320)]}

My program fails when i try to access `jsonload["trades"]`. If i use `jsonload[0]` I only receive one character: `{`.

I checked it isn't a problem from get the text from `stdin`, but I don't know if it is a problem of format received (because i used Incursion library) or if it is a problem in my python code. I have tried many combinations about `json.load/s` and `json.dump/s` but without success.

```
inputdata = sys.stdin.read()

jsondump = json.dumps(inputdata)

jsonload = json.loads(jsondump)

print jsonload
print type(jsonload) # return me "<type 'unicode'>"
print repr(jsonload) # return me same but with u" ..same string.... "
for row in jsonload["trades"]: # error here: TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Your `jsonload` is a `string`, not a `dict`.

Comment: Try `jsonload = json.loads(inputdata)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it return me different error "ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)" but instead when run json.loads

Comment: Then it's possible your `inputdata` *isn't* valid JSON.

Comment: @tobias_k must i convert to dict , before?

Comment: It seems your "json" is not valid JSON at all. What are those `Custom(...)` objects? It looks more like the `repr` of a regular Python dictionary. Maybe you can load it as such, if you have a class called `Custom`

Answer (score 1):

You read input data into a string. This is then turned into a JSON encoded string by `json.dumps`. You then turn it back into a plain string using `json.loads`. You have not interpreted the original data as JSON at any point.

Try just converting the input data from json:

```
inputdata = sys.stdin.read()
jsonload = json.loads(inputdata)
```

However this will not work because you have not got valid JSON data in your snippet. It looks like serialized python code. You can check the input data using http://jsonlint.com

The use of `u'trades'` shows me that you have a unicode python string. The JSON equivalent would be `"trades"`. To convert the python code you can [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do) it, but this is a dangerous operation if the data comes from an untrusted source.

Comment: Yes, print type(jsonload) # return me "<type 'unicode'>" . I read now about eval but it is a trusted environment because i generated the output from another script, but i prefer dont use it. But i cant understand why Incursion library works but not for me , i think so i forgetting something to do in middle.

Comment: In your original code that really just indicates that your strings are unicode. You have not parsed your string so that doesn't actually tell you anything.

Comment: Then i nead research about how to parse unicode, true?

Comment: No, unicode is a format of string. I would suggest that you need to generate JSON data instead of stringified python.