# Menu input of letters return an error

Tags: python

In my python game I'm playing around with I have a menu where you can select to either play the game, load a saved game, save a game, and quit. The input of numbers works fine but when you accidentally or purposefully enter a letter or symbol it returns the error:

```
Choice = eval(input())
File "string", line 1, in module
NameError: name 'y' is not defined"
```

How would I go about fixing this issue?

Function where the error occurs:

```
def DisplayMenu():
    print('1.  Start new game')
    print('2.  Load game')
    print('3.  Save game')
    print('9.  Quit')
    print('Please enter your choice: ')

def GetMainMenuChoice():
    Choice = eval(input())
    return Choice

if not (Choice in ['1','2','3','4','9']):
    print("\n Invalid choice. Enter your option again. \n")
    Choice = False
else:
    Choice = True
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Indent each line with at least 4 spaces for it to appear as code. And please remove the preceding `>` as that acts as a quotation. Otherwise we cannot accurately read and help you with your code.

Comment: don't use eval and worse again it will actually make your code logic incorrect, int can never be equal to a str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `raw_input` if you are using python2, and **don't** use eval, just cast to int if you need an int etc... Unless you have a variable `y` defined somewhere when you try to `eval` the string `y` you will get the error you see, either way eval should rarely if ever be used. The fact your list is full of strings makes trying to make `Choice` and `int` illogical.

```
choice = raw_input() #  input python3

if choice not in {'1','2','3','4','9'}
   ....
```

Use lowercase for variable/function names.

You may also find a while loop to be a nicer approach:

```
def get_main_menu_choice():
    while True:
        choice = raw_input("Please choose an option")
        if choice not in {'1','2','3','4','9'}:
            print("Invalid choice. Enter your option again.")
        else:
            return choice
```

[what-does-pythons-eval-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do)

Comment: Sorry about using eval, I've barely gotten into Python. Your solutions works very well; however when I enter any of the valid inputs it just reprints the menu and doesn't execute what it is meant to. Any ideas?

Comment: Before your amazing update to the menu choice (Thanks again) when you   entered the menu choice it would run the relevant functions and make it work as intended; however with your amendments it now doesn't run the functions after entering your choice. What I want it to do is to run the functions when the relevant option is selected with your new fix to the menu.

Comment: Which functions do you want to run?

Comment: The functions are already implemented into the code. For example Option One will run "Cavern, TrapPositions, MonsterPosition, PlayerPosition, FlaskPosition, MonsterAwake = SetUpGame(Cavern, TrapPositions, MonsterPosition, PlayerPosition, FlaskPosition, MonsterAwake, True)
      PlayGame(Cavern, TrapPositions, MonsterPosition, PlayerPosition, FlaskPosition, MonsterAwake)" which allows the actual game to be played.

Comment: so 1 ,2 ... all correspond to running a certain function?

Comment: Yes and they have all be assigned and work. I just needed to run the menu choice without an input of letters breaking it and causing an error.

Comment: Can you add the code too pastebin, I am pretty sure a dict will be a good solution but seeing the functions and how they are called will confirm

Comment: what do you want to do with choice after the function ends?

Comment: After inputting the choice it should automatically load the functions. The choice returns to 0 after so you can reuse the menu.

Comment: Really you should have all your actual game code in a while loop, calling the appropriate functions along the way so for instance the player dies you can load the menu and ask if they want to play again etc..

Comment: Yeah... I'm not a very confident coder. This is just a sample code I was given to try and learn more from the deliberate mistakes they put in.

Comment: Ah ok, well if you want to return a function based on what number the user enters you can do something like this http://pastebin.com/ZnmwK1H1  if there are cases where not all entrie relate to calling a function you would just check that first and do the necessary