# Give an expression in python

Tags: python

I need help for Boolean expressions. When someone inputs (x or y), (x and y),etc..... It gives a truth table. I have everything except when I try do int((m)) on the line it gives me an error.

```
m = raw_input("Give an expression :")

list=[(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)]

for (x,y) in list:

    print[ x, y ],int(m)
```

Comment: First of all you have `int((n))` not m , then you should not put the `m` in parenthesis,also you need to add the error that you get to question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use eval().

```
m = raw_input("Give an expression :")
list=[(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)]
for (x,y) in list:
    print [ x, y ], eval(m)
```

Example: try `(x and y) or y` when you execute the script.

More information on [What does Python's eval() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned

> "when I try do int((m)) on the line it gives me an error"

Kindly specify exactly what error are you getting.

Comment: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x or y'

Comment: The raw input was x or y