# How to check for a variable name using a string in Python?

Tags: python, variables

For simplicity I'm try to do this.

```
spam = [1,2,3]
stuff = [spam]
x = input()
if x in stuff:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

As it runs:

```
>>> spam
False
```

Of course it doesn't print 'True' because the string 'spam' is not equal to the variable spam.

Is there a simple way of coding that I could check if the input is equal to the variable name? If not simple, anything?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: does it have to be the variable name?  if so, see also http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> spam= [1,2,3]
>>> stuff = [spam]
>>> eval('spam') in stuff
True
```

> DISCLAIMER : do this at your own [risk](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should check the `locals()` and `globals()` dictionaries for the variable. These dictionaries have variable names as keys and their values.

```
spam = [1,2,3]
stuff = [spam]

x = raw_input()

if x in locals() and (locals()[x] in stuff) or \
   x in globals() and (globals()[x] in stuff):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

You can read more on [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) and [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals).

Answer (score 0):

It's a weird idea to try and connect variable names with the world outside the program. How about:

```
data = {'spam':[1,2,3]}

stuff = [data['spam']]

x = raw_input()
if data[x] in stuff:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: You should do `data.get(x)` , if the user gets mischievous and enters a key that is not in the dictionary, your program would fail with `KeyError`

Answer (score 0):

isnt better to use:

```
data = {'spam':[1,2,3]} #create dictionary with key:value
x = input() # get input
print(x in data) #print is key in dictionary (True/False) you might use:
#print(str(x in data)) #- this will convert boolean type name to string value
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @skrilled It looks like an answer to me. A lot of problems are solved by taking a different approach than the OP originally thought.

Comment: Then the answer should elaborate on why it is proper instead of stating something equivalent to "why not try this" - shouldn't it? This attempt does not even begin to elaborate on why it would be a correct answer.