# Using for loop iterator for if condition

Tags: python, loops

I am new to python. I am looking python version of the following shell code.

```
 for (( i=1; i <= 5; i++ ))
 do
       if avg_$i > 0 ; then
       print "Yes!!"
       fi
 done
```

I tried this :

```
    for i in range(1,5):
         if(avg_%d != 0) %(i) :
            print("Yes !! ")
```

It is obvious in other languages. I am sure python will also have an easy way to do it.

Comment: what is `arg_` ? if it is list with arguments used when script was run then you have `sys.argv` for this. Normally you will have to use own list `arg` and `arg[i]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do

Comment: avg_1, avg_2, avg_3  are just float variables.

Comment: I think you should use [`dictionary`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) for `_arg` variable

Comment: As linked by @Prasanth you could use `eval` but it's risky and usually not recommended. Then the line `if(avg_%d != 0) %(i) :` would be `if(eval('avg_%d' % i) > 0) :`

Comment: Yeah. I think that might work thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you would use list `arg` instead of variables `arg_1`, `arg_2`, etc.

```
arg = [1, 4, -5, 15, -1]

for val in arg:
    if val > 0:
       print("yes")
```

So don't try to do  it in the same way as in shell script.

---

If you really need with `i` then you would do

```
arg = [1, 4, -5, 15, -1]

for i in range(len(arg)):
    if arg[i] > 0:
       print("yes")
```

but version without `range(len())` is better

---

Other method with `i` but without `range(len())`

```
arg = [1, 4, -5, 15, -1]

for i, val in enumerate(arg, 1):
    if val > 0:
       print("yes - element number", i)
```

---

**EDIT:** you can also keep it as dictionary

```
data = {
   'arg_1': 1, 
   'arg_2': 4, 
   'arg_3': -5, 
   'arg_4': 15,
   'arg_5': -1
}

for i in range(1, 6):
    if data['arg_{}'.format(i)] > 0:
       print("yes")
```

Comment: That's sad. I had some specific reason to use multiple variables. It's obvious to append in list. I thought python will have some way to deal with that. anyway, thanks ..

Comment: you can also use dictionary `data["arg_{}".format(i) ] > 0` but it makes no sense if you can use list.

Comment: Yeah. I think I will use a list. Thanks !!