# Different behaviors in python console and the editor console

Tags: python

I am new with python and PyCharm. The following code works in python console, listing the functions in the math package:

```
import importlib
st = 'math'
importlib.import_module(st)
dir(eval(st))
```

However, if the same snippet appears in the editor window and runs, the below message shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sywan/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    dir(eval(st))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

Your answer is very much appreciated!!

Comment: It throws `NameError` in both python 2 and python3 console.

Answer (score 1):

[This so answer explains what does eval do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do)

`eval` interprets a string as code. In your case eval convert 'math' into math and search for a variable named math.

```
import importlib
st = 'math'
dir_path = importlib.import_module(st)
dir(dir_path)
```

To find functions in math module, save module path in variable and then apply `dir` method as `importlib.import_module(st)` return st directory path