# How to call a string as a function in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, function, keyboard

I have a string A:

```
import keyboard

A = "keyboard.press_and_release('left windows+R')"
```

But, I want it to work as a function.
If I call A, then it should press Windows Key and R key present on y keyboard.

Comment: Don't have it as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

```
a = "keyboard.press_and_release('left windows+R')"
eval(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `eval`. See https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#eval
or [What does Python's eval() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do#9383764)

```
import keyboard

A = "keyboard.press_and_release('left windows+R')"
eval(A)
```