# Run string command in pymongo

Tags: django, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have following string command

```
query = "{},{'_id': False}"
```

Now I want to run above command in following code

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://'+host+':'+port+'/')
db_col = database.split(',')
database, collection = db_col[0].strip(), db_col[1].strip()
collection = client[database][collection]
collection = collection.find(query).limit(10)
```

Is there any solution for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for above question

I'm convert full query in string and use python eval function to execute on python server.

See following code

This is my string query

```
query = "collection.find({},{'_id': False}).limit(10)"
```

That is how I done in python

```
collection_cursor = eval(query)
```

Comment: Just to point that eval is not recommended https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do