# Convert string to python lists and dictionary?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a string which looks like.

```
"[{'P_Key': 'val1', 'Price': '3.95'}, {'P_Key': 'val2', 'Price': '2.2'}, {'P_Key': 'val3', 'Price': '0.4'}]"
```

I want to convert this into a list of dictionaries like:

```
[{'P_Key': 'val1', 'Price': '3.95'}, 
 {'P_Key': 'val2', 'Price': '2.2'}, 
 {'P_Key': 'val3', 'Price': '0.4'}]
```

There may be any number of such dictionaries in the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

this is safer compare to `eval` as it only evaluate valid python datatypes

```
s = "[{'P_Key': 'val1', 'Price': '3.95'}, {'P_Key': 'val2', 'Price': '2.2'}, {'P_Key': 'val3', 'Price': '0.4'}]"
import ast
ast.literal_eval(s)
# [{'P_Key': 'val1', 'Price': '3.95'}, {'P_Key': 'val2', 'Price': '2.2'}, {'P_Key': 'val3', 'Price': '0.4'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do)

```
 eval("[{'P_Key': 'val1', 'Price': '3.95'}, {'P_Key': 'val2', 'Price': '2.2'}, {'P_Key': 'val3', 'Price': '0.4'}]")
```

Comment: `eval` is dangerous.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Always pass arguments to eval after verifying via regex(easier said than done)?

Comment: much easier said than done but then again already done by `ast.literal_eval`