# How to run printed code Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that runs printed code. For example,

```
def test(mylist):
    mydict = {}
    for i in range(mylist):
        mydict[i] = ('x'+'%s' %i)
        print ("%s = %s" %(mydict[i], i))
test(3)
```

Output:

```
x0 = 0
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
```

I basically want my function to run these printed commands and set `x0=0`, `x1=1`, and so on. I could not think of a way to do it. Thanks!

Edit:

I edited the code based on your dictionary idea. But, it does not still seem to be helping to solve for the gradient of a given function. Can you please help me on this?

```
import sympy as sy
def test(mylist):
    d = {}
    for i in range(mylist):
        d['x'+str(i)] = 'sy.symbols(x%s, real=True)' %i
    return d
test(3)

f = (1/3*x0**6 - 2.1*x0**4 + 4*x0**2 + 
            x0*x1 - 4*x1**2 + 4*x1**4 + x2)
gf = [sy.diff(f, x0), sy.diff(f, x1), sy.diff(f, x2)]
gf
```

Comment: Trying to create dynamic variables is a _baaaaad_ idea. Why not just use the dictionary you're creating?

Comment: [Dupe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do)

Comment: Well, in this case, the dictionary makes sense. But, I want to set `x0` to a long function, where dictionary will be useless.

Comment: Eh, not really @user202729. The user's not explicitly asking about `eval`, although that is the function is would need to `use` (but definitely not _should!_). There are duplicates out there though, just keep searcin' :-)

Comment: @user202729 Huh? I'm really sure what your asking here. Can you be more specific. Or better yet, edit your answer to show exactly what you want.

Comment: Edited with one more example to clarify.

Comment: Then how do you intend to use those `x0, x1, x2` variables? By typing out their names? In that case you can as well type the definition out explicitly.

Comment: What about `x[0] = sy.symbols('x0', real=True)`?

Comment: The same thing could be done in your newly posted example, @user8028576 . just assign the return value of each call to `sy.symbols` to a key in a dictionary. I'm sorry, but i'm still no sure why you can't use a dictionary?

Comment: I still think a dictionary is not doing what I need. Am I really missing it? @ChristianDean

Comment: Hold up, @user8028576. Gimme five and I'll post an answer to clear things up :-)

Comment: Alright, @user8028576. Sorry about the wait, my answers up though.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, dictionaries are the way to go. Stylistically, get in the habit of using `return` rather than printing results.

I've made some changes to your code, which should illustrate these points:

```
def test(mylist):
    d = {}
    for i in range(mylist):
        d['x'+str(i)] = i
    return d

test(3)  # {'x0': 0, 'x1': 1, 'x2': 2}
```

Comment: Your code could be condensed if you used a dictionary comprehension `return {'x' + str(i) for i in range(mylist)}`.

Comment: Agreed - but one step at a time!

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but we don't know _for sure_ if the OP is new to Python ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to create dynamic variables is almost always a bad idea. It's dangers and often unnecessarily pollutes a namespace. However, I agree that just using plain variables here would be easier. Thus, you can return a list of values from `test`, and unpack them into three variables (`x0`, `x1`, and `x2`):

Create a list of your values:

```
def test(mylist):
    return [sy.symbols('x' + str(n), real=True) for n in range(mylist)]
```

And then create your `gf` list using the values in the list:

```
x0, x1, x2 = test(3)
f = (1/3*x0**6 - 2.1*x0**4 + 4*x0**2 + x0*x1 - 4*x1**2 + 4*x1**4 + x2)
gf = [sy.diff(f, x0), sy.diff(f, x1), sy.diff(f, x2)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but, writing: `x0, x1, x2 = test(3)` is what I want to avoid. I could also do the same. What if I have 100 variables?

Comment: @user8028576 You _could_ use a list comprehension to create your `gf` list (`gf = [sy.diff(f, v) for v in test(3)]`), but I'm not sure how you'd evaluate your `f` equation? Is there a way it can be generalized?

Comment: Arranging gf is the secondary task. If I could generalize xi= 'sy.symbols(xi, real=True). Then, it could be meaningful.