# Running a .py file from a FileField

Tags: django

I have a model that contains a FileField. I use it to upload .py files.

**models.py**

```
class FileModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(null = True, blank = True, upload_to = 'files')
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I want to retrieve the uploaded files and execute the code within a view.

**views.py**

```
def get_return_from_file(request):
    post = FileModel.objects.get(file_name__iexact='example_name')
    a = post.file.read()
    print (a)
```

**Example uploaded python file 'example_name'**

```
def main():
    return 'hello world'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However this returns

> b'def main():\n return 'hello world'\n if **name** == "**main**":\n main()'

instead of

> 'hello world'

How can I execute the code in the FileField and access it's returned values instead of just reading it as a string?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to be very sure that folks won't upload malicious code if you're going to do this ...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#exec

Comment: Similar thread here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do

Answer (score 0):

example file:

```
def main():
    return 'hello world'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main())
```

views.py

```
def get_return_from_file(request):
    post = FileModel.objects.get(file_name__iexact='example_name')
    a = post.file.read()
    exec(a)
```

Comment: This doesn't return 'hello world', if I instead write in views.py print (exec(a)) it returns None which suggests django isn't reading the uploaded file with this method.

Comment: thats because you are not returning any thing from your example .py file

Answer (score -1):

Use `eval()` for single line expression.

`eval()` only returns expression result.

Use `exec()` for statements, any valid python code block.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html