# Transform a string to some code in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I store some data in a excel that I extract in a JSON format. I also call some data with GET requests from some API I created. With all these data, I do some test (does the data in the excel = the data returned by the API?)

In my case, I may need to store in the excel the way to select the data from the API json returned by the GET.

for example, the API returns :

```
{"countries":
    [{"code":"AF","name":"Afghanistan"},
     {"code":"AX","name":"Åland Islands"} ...
```

And in my excel, I store :

```
excelData['countries'][0]['name']
```

I can retrieve the `excelData['countries'][0]['name']` in my code just fine, as a string.

Is there a way to convert `excelData['countries'][0]['name']` from a string to some code that actually points and get the data I need from the API json?

here's how I want to use it :

```
self.assertEqual(str(valueExcel), path) 
#path is the string from the excel that tells where to fetch the data from the
# JSON api
```

I thought strings would be interpreted but no :

```
AssertionError: 'AF' != "excelData['countries'][0]['code']"
- AF
+ excelData['countries'][0]['code']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) method. Try with this:

```
self.assertEqual(str(valueExcel), eval(path))
```

> **Important:** Keep in mind that `eval` can be dangerous, since malicious code could be executed. More warnings here: [What does Python's eval() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do)

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is a safer alternative if you do some string splices, use `literal_eval` to get the dictionary keys than manually put that keys in the dictionary. It would require some string splicing but would be safer. Just another alternative.

Comment: Thanks, never seen that method before. I plan to use that only for tests and only the admins can execute them. And quick note, it's on the `path ` variable that I needed the `eval`.