# Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to python.my code is below -

```
reading_range = "0:54, 2:34" #this is my variable 
data.iloc[reading_range]  #this line is giving error ,because the value is coming as '0:54, 2:34'
```

but I want something like

```
data.iloc[0:54, 2:34]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please consider accept my answer if you find it's possible. Or tell me is there something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
index = reading_range.split(',')
eval('data.iloc[{}, {}]'.format(index[0], index[1]))
```

see what `eval()` does: [What does Python's eval() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do)

Comment: Maybe add new link - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice/1832957#1832957)

Answer (score 3):

The colon and comma are syntactical sugar, for a tuple and `slice(..)` objects. You can generate something equivalent like:

```
reading_range = slice(0,54), slice(2,34)
data.iloc[reading_range]
```