# How to convert string represntaion of list containing namedtuple into normal list

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I am trying to convert string representation of list containing namedtuples into normal list.

Tried eval_literal, json.loads and split.

Error with ast.literal_eval

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x7f834bef5860>
```

After adding double quotes to string

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Error with json.loads()

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Problem with split is it is converting data types of contents of the namedtuple.

Please suggest me possible solution.
input :

```
'[milestone(id=1, amount=1000, curency='inr'), milestone(id=1, amount=1000, curency='inr')]'
type<str>
```

expected output:

```
[milestone(id=1, amount=1000, curency='inr'), milestone(id=1, amount=1000, curency='inr')]
type<list>
```

Comment: `literal_eval` is for *literals*, which e.g. `milestone(id=1, ...)` is not.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#eval) (StackOverflow thread about [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do)):

```
from collections import namedtuple

str = "[milestone(id=1, amount=1000, currency='inr'), milestone(id=1, amount=1000, currency='inr')]"

milestone = namedtuple('milestone', 'id amount currency')
list = eval(str)
print(list)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY6xCsMwDER3f4XoYhs8JHT2l5QOwVGpwJaMrRTy9W4KJZ27Pu7uXd31KXwd49GkQJKcMSkJd6BSpSnwUnDVrWY0xnRtEOFyK5SxqzA6WuMcYCmyscZ5mqYAaWsNOe3REjfrA/yTvl@MOfOH66d39uQ2gKX1u3MuWG8ydT1K@FqyO756Uxuxug/2Y7wB)

By the way, two `r` in currency ;)

Comment: I read in most of the articles that eval is dangerous. Is it safe to use eval?

Comment: If you control the input, you should be fine. In most case, I would avoid using eval. What the best solution here? Serialize the original output to a well defined format (json, xml, whatever) and deserialize it with Python for usage. Another solution would be to build your own nametuple parser.