# How can I make my program create variables automatically and print them by it self?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got an idea for a program that I'm not sure how to implement. How can I make the program ask the user something -- `input()` -- as many times as user responds until x command is written and (and this is the hard part) create variables automatically (e.g answer1 = x, answer2 = x, answer3 = x, answer4 = x) with their respective value assigned?
 And how could I then print all those variables without having to write them manually, for example, if at the beginning 6 variables were created then the 6 variables will be printed. 
 I'm not asking you to write it all for me, conversely I want you to give me some tips, some functions or ideas and I will be more than grateful. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possibly of interest:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do

Comment: ... why not just use a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)?

Comment: Use a list, you can append to it and iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, python lists should be a better solution to your problem. You can simply create an empty list:

```
answers = []
```

and then follow with something like this:

```py
string = input()
while string != x:
    answers.append(string)
    string = input()

print(answers)
```

Comment: I've been working on this and I got another question. How can I multiply every number in the list by a variable which has a float number?

Comment: I understand that it has to be int but I need the exact number in the variable

Comment: @gonza I'm not sure what you're asking. You cannot multiply a string and a float without throwing an error. If you want the list to contain numerical values, then it would be possible