# Python switch case, multiple value

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to execute multiple value in python dictionary?

```
def func1():
    pass
def func2():
    pass
def func3():
    pass
def func4():


def main_menu():
    os.system('clear')
    print("\nWelcome, \n\n")
    print("1. First Question")
    print("2. Second Question")
    print("\n\n Type 'q' for Quit\n")
    choice = input(" >>  ").lower()
    if choice == '':
        main_menu()
    else:
        try:
            main_menus[choice]()
        except KeyError:
            print("Invalid selection, Please try again.\n")
            main_menu()
    return

main_menus = {
    '1' : func1, 
    '2' : func2, 
}
```

i want `main_menus` key have two value, like this for example

```
main_menus = {
    '1' : func1, func4
    '2' : func2, func3
}
```

so, if user input `'1'`, it will execute `func1` first, after finish, it will execute `func4`..
i can't call `func4` from `func1` like this:

```
def func1():
    return func4()
```

because `func1`, maybe will be use by another `main_menus` key, and will be pair with `func3`..

anyone have solution for this, if can, better not use for loop.

Thank you

Comment: Look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1 Using Eval**

```
main_menus = {
    '1' : "func1(), func2()",
    '2' : "func2(), func3(),func4()"
}

try:
    eval(main_menus[choice])
```

Overall Code becomes:

```
import os

def func1():
  pass

def func2():
  pass

def func3():
  pass

def func4():
  pass

def main_menu():
  choice = ''
  while True:
    os.system('clear')
    print("\nWelcome, \n\n")
    print("1. First Question")
    print("2. Second Question")
    print("\n\n Type 'q' for Quit\n")

    choice = input(" >>  ").lower()
    if choice != 'q':
      try:
        eval(main_menus[choice])
      except KeyError:
          print("Invalid selection, Please try again.\n")
    else:
      break

  return


main_menus = {
    '1' : "func1(), func2()",
    '2' : "func2(), func3(),func4()"
}

main_menu()
```

**Option 2 -- Use For Loop**

Replace main_menus and try are in overall code above with:

```
main_menus = {
    '1' : [func1, func2],
    '2' : [func2, func3, func4]
}

try:
    for f in main_menus[choice]:
        f()
```

Comment: yes, i have try this before, it can..but maybe there is another way without for loop, because i have so many `keys` in that dictionary..

Comment: @Fixlensmith--updated with the option of using eval, although I don't understand your issue with a for loop.  Could you explain further?

Comment: i just want to know if there is another way, i just want to compare the speed between for loop and other option.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a function that calls both of them.

```
def func12():
    func1()
    func2()
def func34():
    func3()
    func4()

main_menus = {
    '1': func12,
    '2': func34
}
```