# Execute user entered Python commands from Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am looking for a way to be able to run a python command from a Tkinter GUI. (I am using python 2.7.)

Example:

```
import Tkinter
root = Tk()

def run():
   print 'smth'

def runCommand():
   code...

button = Button(root, text = 'smth', command = run).pack()

entry = Entry(root, width = 55, justify = 'center').pack()
entry_button = Button(root, text = 'Run', command = runCommand).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I would like to type `print 'hello'` in the entry and when I press <kbd>Run</kbd> button it actually runs the command `print 'hello'`

How is this doable? If it is not, than can I add a command line widget in Tkinter?

Comment: You can try `eval()` or `exec()`.  But you need to use it wisely.

Comment: Read [AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101765/7414759)

Comment: Where's should the output from the commands be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to evaluate expressions (like `print 'hello`) one at a time, `eval()` is what you're looking for.

```
def runCommand():
   eval(entry.get())
```

Another option is `exec()`; you'll have to [decide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile) whether you like one or the other better for your use case. The possible dangers have already been described better than I might be able to:

> A user can use this as an option to run code on the computer. If you have eval(input()) and os imported, a person could type into input() os.system('rm -R *') which would delete all your files in your home directory.
>   Source: [CoffeeRain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do/9384005#answer-9384005)

Do note (as stovfl mentioned) that you ought to declare and pack your widgets separately.

That is, change this:

```
entry = Entry(root, width = 55, justify = 'center').pack()
```

to this:

```
entry = Entry(root, width = 55, justify = 'center')
entry.pack()
```

Otherwise, you end up storing the value of `pack()` (which is `None`) instead of storing your widgets (the `Button` and `Entry` objects)