# converting a list of type [("['str']", int), ("['str']", int)] to [('str', int), ('str', int)]

Tags: python, list

i have a list of   type

```
[("['106.52.116.101']", 1), ("['45.136.108.85']", 1)]
```

and want to convert it to

```
[('106.52.116.101', 1), ('45.136.108.85', 1)]
```

Comment: The simplest way is probably `[(s[2:-2], n) for s, n in xs]`

Comment: Are the brackets before and after the str always at the same place? (First and last character?)

Comment: Is that list purported str will alway have one item in it? Or it may be something like `"['106.52.116.101', 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx']"` in the furher items?

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one way to solve this, you can do this for example:

```
lst = [("['106.52.116.101']", 1), ("['45.136.108.85']", 1)]
new = [(l[0][2:-2], l[1]) for l in lst]
print(new)
```

Output:

```
[('106.52.116.101', 1), ('45.136.108.85', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() of string as below:

```
lst = [("['106.52.116.101']", 1), ("['45.136.108.85']", 1)]
print(lst)
new_lst = [(first.split('\'')[1], sec)for first, sec in lst]
print(new_lst)
```

**output**

```
[("['106.52.116.101']", 1), ("['45.136.108.85']", 1)]                                                                   
[('106.52.116.101', 1), ('45.136.108.85', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

l = [("['106.52.116.101']", 1), ("['45.136.108.85']", 1)]
l = [(literal_eval(f)[0], s) for f, s in l]
l
```

**output:**

```
[('106.52.116.101', 1), ('45.136.108.85', 1)]
```

​

Answer (score -1):

*Mateen Ulhaq* already presented a very short and good solution.

But if the array does not always have one item in it you can use this:

```
[(eval(s)[0], n) for s, n in list]
```

As `eval()` interpretes python code the strings have to be syntactically correct. Also [pay attention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9384005/9839378) if these strings come from a user in terms of security.