# Calling automated function out of a variable

Tags: python-3.x, string, function

```
def Test_1():
    x = 1
    for i in range(0,6):
        y = "Road" + str(x) + "()"
        y
        x = x + 1
        print("end")
```

What would be the correct way to call Function: Road1() - Road6() ?
Like this :

```
def Test_1():
    Road1()
    Road2()
    Road3()
    Road4()
    ...
    Road6()
    print("end")
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is being asked here, but this seems to be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables). If you're trying to dynamically create variables/functions though, using a dictionary or list would be much better.

Comment: what you want is `eval`. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def Test_1():
    for x in range(1,7):
        y = "Road" + str(x) + "()"
        eval(y)
    print("end")
```

**EDIT** Aug 2022: Using `eval` is not a good idea. In Python we can call functions using its name string as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3061/8363478)