# Extract tensor from string

Tags: string, pytorch, tensor

Is it possible to extract directly the tensor included in this string `tensor([-1.6975e+00,  1.7556e-02, -2.4441e+00, -2.3994e+00, -6.2069e-01])`? I'm looking for some `tensorflow` or `pytorch` function that can do it, like the `ast.literal_eval` function does for dictionaries and lists.

If not, could you provide a pythonic method, please?

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
tensor_list = "tensor([-1.6975e+00,  1.7556e-02, -2.4441e+00, -2.3994e+00, -6.2069e-01])"
str_list = tensor_list.replace("tensor(", "").replace(")", "")
l = ast.literal_eval(str_list)
torch.from_numpy(np.array(l))
```

But I'm not sure this is the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
import torch.tensor as tensor

eval(tensor_list)
>>> tensor([-1.6975,  0.0176, -2.4441, -2.3994, -0.6207])
```

Comment: Does the `eval` function recognize the tensor inside the string? this is awesome!

Comment: [`eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740) will run string as python code. and we have added alias for `tensor` before (`import torch.tensor as tensor`) so it worked.