# Loading n-dimensional tensor for pytorch from text file

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I have a 3-dimensional tensor that I create outside of my python code and am able to encode in any human-readable format. I need to load the values of this tensor as a frozen layer to my `pytorch` NN. I've tried to encode the tensor as a text file in the form `[[[a,b],[c,d]], [[e,f], [g,h]], [[k,l],[m,n]]]` which seemed to be the most logical way for that. Then I tried to read its value via

```
tensor = torch.from_numpy(np.loadtxt("./arrays/tensor.txt"))
```

but got the exception in `npyio.py`

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[[[-2.888356,'
```

Apparently, that's not how it works and the values are to be written as plain numbers separated by spaces and `\n`, but then I don't see how to easily read the data of dimension >= 2 with `numpy`.

What could be other simple methods to write down and read the tensor value into a `pytorch` tensor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract tensor from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814427/extract-tensor-from-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using Python's built-in `eval`? In case you saved your tensor as a list in text file you may try something as follows:

```
with open("./arrays/tensor.txt","r") as f:
    loaded_list = eval(f.read())
loaded_tensor = torch.tensor(loaded_list)
```

`eval` will take care of converting your string to a list and then just cast the result to a `Tensor` by using `torch.tensor()`. The loaded tensor will then be in `loaded_tensor` as required.

Comment: My pleasure! :)