# How to convert a full string output into torch tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pytorch

Having defined an API based on a transformer model which I send request to, I got as output an object of class string supposed to represent a torch tensor.

```
import requests
import json
import torch

response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict", json="This is a test.")
data = response.json()
print(data)

tensor([[-5.5169e-01,  5.1988e-01, -1.4731e-01,  4.6096e-02, -5.5753e-02,
         -6.9530e-01,  7.3424e-01,  3.0014e-01,  4.0528e-01, -1.7587e-01,
          1.2586e-01,  5.6712e-01, -4.0757e-01,  1.5796e-01,  9.4700e-01,
          6.2967e-01,  3.1027e-01,  1.0169e-02,  3.1380e-02,  1.2585e-01,
          2.3633e-01,  6.0813e-01, -1.0548e+00, -1.8581e-01, -5.9870e-02,
          1.2952e-01, -3.8818e-01,  2.3425e-01]])
```

I checked in the `requests` module documentation, but couldn't find any way to convert this fully strings into a torch tensor?

Comment: The simplest way could be to import `tensor` from TensorFlow and then `eval(data, globals={'tensor': tensor})`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract tensor from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814427/extract-tensor-from-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval` to evaluate the code contained in the string:

```py
from torch import tensor

my_tensor = eval(data)
```