# how to unstringify arrays without external modules with python?

Tags: python, arrays, string

How to turn a string that contains an array into a normal array without using external modules? For example: `“a[0]”` into `a[0]`

**edit:**
I have seen a few complains about the amount of information in this post so I will add some more details about my problem for everyone watching this in future: My intention was to write a string that contains `”array[…]”` somewhere in it but I need to execute this array somehow and my best choice was to remove the quotes around it but I don’t want to use `eval()` because of a few security issues

**edit 2:**
or tell me, how to express an equation in python without instantly solving it and without importing modules

Comment: I not sure but maybe `eval` might help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does Python's eval() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: `globals()["array"][...]` together with string processing `"array[…]".partition('[')` to separate the identifier from the "positions"

Answer (score 0):

one option is to use builtin `eval` function in python:

```py
a = [  'wowweeeee!' ]

print(eval('a[-1]'))  # wowweeeee!
```

as @cards mentions in the comments, you can also pass a local `dict` object to restrict the scope of `eval`, to help address any security concerns:

```py
try:
    print(eval('a[-1]', {'a': a}))  # wowweeeee!

except NameError as ne:
    print('following variable is missing:', ne)
```

Comment: is it the only option? just asking because of some security issues with eval

Comment: @anyone `eval` accept arguments to restrict the scope, i.e. `eval('a[-1]', {'a':a})`

Comment: thanks, I updated my ans above to reflect this new info :-)