# Why is my eval command not showing any output?

Tags: python, eval

I have defined a function eval_loop in which I prompt the user with a command in which I ask him to evaluate an expression. The expression I want to evaluate is "2+2". If the user presses done or Done, the while loop will exit. Why am I not able to receive any output when I type "2+2"? Why is the eval command not showing any output?

```
def eval_loop ():
    while True:
        line=input("enter the expression you want to evaluate:")
        if line == "done" or "Done":
            break
        else:
            y=eval(line)
            print(y)
        print (done)

eval_loop()
```

Comment: As an additional note, `eval` is widely considered to be a security risk. You want to import the `ast` library, then call `ast.literal_eval` instead, which is much safer.

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection, [What does Python's eval() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/), https://stackoverflow.com/a/37081082/15032126. And you can just search for many many more examples...

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug that keeps `eval` from running. `if line == "done" or "Done":` is the same as `if (line == "done") or "Done"` and since `"Done"` is always `True`, you break out of the loop before doing anything.

You could change that to`if line == "done" or line == "Done"`, but I would suggest that you normalize the input (change it to a common form) and catch more spellings of "done".

(That last print is a bug too because the variable `done` does not exist.)

```
def eval_loop ():
    while True:
        line=input("enter the expression you want to evaluate:")
        if line.lower() == "done":
            break
        else:
            y=eval(line)
            print(y)
        print ("done")

eval_loop()
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much but can you please tell me why my last line, print "done", is a bug? There I have written "done" with lowercase d?

Comment: You wrote the variable name `done` which doesn't exist. I assumed you wanted the string `"done"` so made that change in my code.